# What is the relationship between 2 entities in my case - staff and customer?

Tags: mysql, sql, erd

I have `Staff`, `Customer`, `Order`, `OrderItems`, `Stock` tables. My tables are listed below, and the relationships are with them. I am trying to create a relationship between `Customer` and `Staff`. My goal is to have it so that one customer is served by one staff member.

| Staff. | Customer. | Order. | OrderItems. | Stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| staffID PK | customerID PK | orderID PK | orderID PK/FK | stockID PK |
| forename | forename | customerID FK | stockID PK/FK | name |
| surname | surname |  | quantity. | quantityInStock |
| role |  | date/time. |  |  |

I have tried to put the `staffID` as a FK in `Customer` table but then realised that would not be suitable since `customerID` 1, John, Smith can have multiple orders on different days therefore it would end up being repeated.

My idea is to put `staffID` as a FK in `Order` table to avoid repeating data. But how would the relationship work between `Customer` and `Staff`?

Without staff table, the current relationships are: Customer < Order < orderItems > Stock.

Comment: Looks like you're looking at it the wrong way around. It is "order > customer" and "orderitem > order". Similarly it would be "order > staff". Problem solved.

Comment: There is no direct relationship between customer and staff, the relationship is implicit via the order

Comment: Do I just add a staffID as a FK inside the order table then?

Answer (score 0):

Since one customer is served by one staff member only, you should put the staff ID in the Order table as FK. Therefore one customer can have multiple orders, one orders can contains multiple stock items. And each order will be served by one staff 
The relationship would be : 
Customer (1 to Many) Order 
Staff (1 to Many) Order 
Order (1 to Many) OrderItems 
Stock (1 to Many) OrderItems

| Staff | Customer | Stock | Order | OrderItems |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| staffID pk | customerID PK | stockID PK | orderID PK | orderID PK/FK |
| forename | forename | name | customerID FK | stockID PK/FK |
| surname | surname | quantityInStock | **staffID FK** | quantity |
| role |  |  | date/time |  |